# Which type of schema.org should I use for country/city advices?

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta, schema.org, microdata

Could you please help me out, which type of [schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) should I use in this structure?

```html
<h1>Country or city name</h1>
<div id="country_info">some info</div>

<div class="advice">
     <div class="date">03-03-2015</div>
     <div class="tags"><a href="">tag1</a> <a href="">tag2</a></div>
             <div class="text">
             user text...
             </div>
     <div class="author">name</div>
</div>

<div class="advice">
     <div class="date">05-05-2015</div>
     <div class="tags"><a href="">tag5</a> <a href="">tag1</a></div>
             <div class="text">
             user text...
             </div>
     <div class="author">name2</div>
</div>
```

and so on …

Is it a "*Place*" and "*Comment*" types, "*Place*" with no physical address? Or maybe a "*Blog*"/"*BlogPosting*" type? I'm confused.

These user texts are short. Each text is not enough for an article. But the full page becomes very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at [`Thing`](http://schema.org/Thing) and check its "More specific Types". Select the types that seem to match and check their definitions. Go as deep/detailed as possible. That’s it.

You’ll see that each advice is a [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork). Check its "More specific Types". Only you can know what these advices really are.

- If these are random advices about a country/city, you probably should look at [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article). None of its sub-types (`BlogPosting`, `NewsArticle`, `ScholarlyArticle`, `TechArticle`) seem to be appropriate, so stay with `Article`. There is no "too short" for an article, they don’t have to be long.
- If these are advices for a specific problem, [`Answer`](http://schema.org/Answer) could be appropriate.
- From the information you’ve given in your question, [`Comment`](http://schema.org/Comment) doesn’t seem to be appropriate.
- It’s only a [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) if these are part of a blog.

You could use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about) to reference the country ([`Country`](http://schema.org/Country)/[`State`](http://schema.org/State)) or city ([`City`](http://schema.org/City)) the advice is about.

So the structure could look like this in Microdata:

```html
<section itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City" id="city">
  <h1 itemprop="name">City name</h1>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="city">
  </article>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" itemref="city">
  </article>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing we need to figure out is what is the objective of the info. It seems your main objective is to show a Country or a City, so probably your best choice is Country or City. Keep in mind that this types include the Thing properties that includes description, name, image, ... that could serve to include the rest of the parameter. For example, the user comments would be the "description" property.

When you want figure out what type of schema you must use think in the main you want to offer to browsers or apps. If you are talking about Countries, then Country is your type, if you are talking about Persons, then Person is your choice. But never use Person if you are talking about countries although it seems that your fields fit better in that scheme.